# Not redirecting after submitting the form in php

Tags: php, html, form-submit

After submitting my form i am not able to redirect to successful page.

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<title>Feel Free to send us your Thoughts</title>
<?php
$to         ='sanaullahkhan81@gmail.com';
$name       =$_POST['name'];
$email      =$_POST['email'];
$message    =$_POST['message'];
$subject    ='Enquiry using Contact us page from:  '.$name ;
$actul_msg  ='A Message from Contact Us Page'. "\n".'Name: '.$name."\n".' Eamil: 
'.$email."\n" .' Enquiry: '.$message;
mail($to,$subject,$actul_msg);
header('Location: sucessfully_submitted.html');
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Here's [a link](http://epbuys.co.uk/contacts.html)

link for success page
here's [a link](http://epbuys.co.uk/sucessfully_submitted.html)

Comment: Than what happens display blank page or something ? Also add `exit;` after header redirect code. And remove `ob_end_clean();` it must be hiding text if any.

Comment: try keeping <title>Feel Free to send us your Thoughts</title> at the bottom of above code

Comment: remove `ob_start();` and `ob_end_clean();` and put `exit;` after `header`.

Comment: if i remove ob-start this error show    `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one
i found the answers. i followed these steps.
Added `ob_start();` on the top.
Added `ob_end_clean();` at the end.
started my `<?php` at the first line of the page with no space

Answer (score 5):

How the manual says: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

```
<?php

$to         ='sanaullahkhan81@gmail.com';
$name       =$_POST['name'];
$email      =$_POST['email'];
$message    =$_POST['message'];
$subject    ='Enquiry using Contact us page from:  '.$name ;
$actul_msg  ='A Message from Contact Us Page'. "\n".'Name: '.$name."\n".' Eamil: 
'.$email."\n" .' Enquiry: '.$message;
mail($to,$subject,$actul_msg);
header('Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/sucessfully_submitted.html');

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Header Location always needs to be a absolute URI ( http://yourdomain.com/foo.html )

`header("Location: http://www.example.com/");` ( see [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) )

**Reference from php.net**

> Note:
>
> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including
>   the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept
>   relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
>   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a
>   relative one yourself

Comment: This is not true, you can do header('Location: sucessfully_submitted.html'); as long as sucessfully_submitted.html is in the same directory as the calling php script.

Comment: yes done no luck `<?php
ob_start();
$to   ='sanaullahkhan81@gmail.com';
$name  =$_POST['name'];
$email  =$_POST['email'];
$message =$_POST['message'];
$subject ='Enquiry using Contact us page from:  '.$name ;

$actul_msg ='A Message from Contact Us Page'. "\n".'Name: '.$name."\n".' Eamil: '.$email."\n" .' Enquiry: '.$message;
mail($to,$subject,$actul_msg);
header('Location: http://epbuys.co.uk/sucessfully_submitted.html');
ob_end_clean();
exit;
?>`

Comment: @NicholasKing yes indeed its in same directory

Comment: @webdevelopersana your problem is as steven has noted that you are sending doing your redirect after sending http headers. You need to move all output bellow the header redirect code.

Comment: From the php.net website: `Note:

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself`

Comment: Yes, but I don't think you want to write software for "Some clients".

Comment: I think you will find that is exactly how software is written!